# Issue with assigning output from a function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, bioinformatics

I am having problem when I try to store rmabackadj function's output to a variable. The function works properly when no output variable is assigned. This function is part of bioinformatics toolbox.

So the issue is when I try to run the following it works properly:

```
rmabackadj(myprobeData.PMIntensities)
```

But when I try to run the following I get an error:

```
>> A = rmabackadj(myprobeData.PMIntensities)
Warning: Colon operands must be real scalars. 
> In rmabackadj>findMaxDensity at 255
  In rmabackadj at 164 
Error using ksdensity>parse_args (line 162)
X must be a non-empty vector.
Error in ksdensity (line 114)
[axarg,yData,n,ymin,ymax,xispecified,xi,u,m,kernelname,...
Error in rmabackadj>findMaxDensity (line 255)
[f, x] = ksdensity(z,  min(z):(max(z)-min(z))/npoints:max(z), 'kernel', 'epanechnikov');
Error in rmabackadj (line 164)
            mu = findMaxDensity( o(o < mu));
```

I searched for it online as well, but I couldn't find any result. Does anybody have any idea about the cause of this error?

PS: When I assign ans variable to a new variable, it is properly assigned.

```
A = ans
```

Comment: Minor technicality: `rmabackadj` is not built-in, it's part of the Bioinformatics Toolbox.

Comment: What version of the Bioinformatic Toolbox are you running?

Comment: From the [doc](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/bioinfo/ref/rmabackadj.html) it seems like you should be able to assign an output argument. Does the same problem also occur when you try it with the given example? Try running it with `dbstop if error` to see whether you can get any hint as to why it jams and verify that none of the used functions is overloaded by something you made yourself. Finally, does it help when you clear `A` first?

Comment: `myprobeData.PMIntensities` is an array of probe intensity values generated by `celintensityread`function.

Comment: Question is now also posted here: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/87981-can-t-assign-output-from-a-built-in-function

Comment: @EitanT  I am running Version 4.2, MATLAB 2012b.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin I am now trying to find the porblem using the debug mode. Thanks. I will come back with more information. And about clearing the variable, I tried but it didn't work. Same problem.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin I couldn't find the problem, but I could generate the error using MATLAB's example data:
`load prostatecancerrawdata;`

`A = rmabackadj(pmMatrix(1:10001,:));`

Comment: Update:

I checked rmabackadj function and found that the function doesn't handle the estimation of mu properly.

  `% estimate initial guess for mu`
  `mu = findMaxDensity(o);`
  `% estimate mu from left-of-the-mode data`
  `mu = findMaxDensity( o(o < mu));`

First estimate, gives a value for mu, but since there is no o<mu and the second findMaxDensity function above, returns an empty mu value which overwrites the previous one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mathworks confirmed this bug and issued a work around for it and mentioned this may be fixed in future releases.

One possible workaround is to add the following conditional at line 163 of `rmabackadj` function

```
% estimate mu from left-of-the-mode data
  if any(o < mu)
     mu = findMaxDensity( o(o < mu));
  end
```

The bug for N<1000 samples has been confirmed as well but no work around has been issued yet.

I will update the thread if the work around for N<1000 samples bug.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure this is a bug.

Firstly, the reason it errors only when you supply an output argument is because there's an internal switch in the function that calculates different things based on `nargout`. That's an odd design, but not necessarily a bug.

Internal to `rmabackadj` there are two subfunctions `findMaxDensity` and `findMaxDensity2`. The main routine calls `findMaxDensity`, which is supposed to find an initial guess for the parameter `mu`. However (when I run the documentation example that you mention in your comment), it finds a terrible guess right on the edge, leading to an error.

When I edit the file to call `findMaxDensity2` rather than `findMaxDensity`, it seems to produce a reasonable guess, and runs fine with no error. I can't vouch for whether the guess is actually "correct", but it seems reasonable to me, and it's only functioning as an initial guess to start off a better estimation process. (NB if you do this yourself, make sure to save a copy of the old version first).

I would guess that this is a bug, either that `findMaxdensity` is generating an unusually poor guess that should be caught, or that really it should be calling `findMaxDensity2` and the code has not been updated to call a new subfunction.

Either way, I would [report](http://www.mathworks.com/support/service_requests/contact_support.do) it to MathWorks.

PS I am running MATLAB R2011b. Check first if the issue has been fixed, or behaves differently, in more recent versions.

Comment: You're absolutely right. The `rmabackadj`function also fails when you try to call it with less than 1000 samples. In `rmabackadj` there is a clause to check for N<1000, but when it doesn't handle it properly. To recreate the bug, try to load the same prostate cancer raw data example and ask it to normalise less than 1000 samples.

I have reported this bug to MATHWORKS and if they provide any sort of information I will answer here.